# maven-jaxb2-plugin multiple schemas in different packages Error

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a problem with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` . 
What I am trying to achieve is to generate-sources from x different wsdl's into different packages.

I would like to avoid method with multiple `<execution>` so I could leave pom.xml untouched when I add another wsdl.

I configured maven plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>orig/*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>

                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>orig/*.xjb</include>
                    </bindingIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In my understanding, this way I specified .wsdl locations as well as binding files locations.

Now in a example binding file (all of them are constructed the same way) I got following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    jaxb:version="2.1">


    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../wsdl/orig/soap1.wsdl"
        node="*/xs:schema">

        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.com.soap1" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Another services are soap2, soap3 etc. all of them have similar binding files. If i understand this correct, thanks to that connfig i should be able to generate domain objects for my soap's each in separate package.

But when i run `maven clean compile` i got the following output:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/me/workspace/orig-project/src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl/orig/soap1.wsdl{202,39}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/me/workspace/orig-project/src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl/orig/soap1.wsdl; lineNumber: 202; columnNumber: 39; 'Line' **is already defined**
```

What is more, for testing purposes I have tried configuring plugin to process each wsdl in separate `<execution>` (I want to avoid that in final code) and what i observed is that after first ex. soap1.wsdl was processed, the package was properly created but other soap.wsdl's packages wasn't created at all. (only first was processed).

**What is wrong with that, and if it is possible to achieve what I want?**

**UPDATE:**
To clarify what I want to achieve I will post there solution that is working for me, but it forces me to edit POM every time I add new webservice:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>soap1</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>

                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>Soap1.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <generatePackage>my.package.com.soap1</generatePackage>
                </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>soap2</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>Soap2.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>my.package.com.soap2</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>soap3</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>Soap3.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/webservice/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>soap3.xjb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
            <generatePackage>my.package.com.soap3</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It looks like (maybe?) there is some problem with:

```
<jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="my.package.com.soap1" />
</jaxb:schemaBindings>
```

in my first (and wanted) solution. Any ideas?